# Spring: how do I inject an HttpServletRequest into a request-scoped bean?

Tags: java, spring, servlets

I'm trying to set up a [request-scoped bean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-other) in Spring.

I've successfully set it up so the bean is created once per request. Now, it needs to access the HttpServletRequest object.

Since the bean is created once per request, I figure the container can easily inject the request object in my bean. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 152, accepted):

Request-scoped beans can be autowired with the request object.

```
private @Autowired HttpServletRequest request;
```

Comment: Is there an old fashioned XML way for this?

Comment: @cherouvim: I don't think so, no. The current request object is not visible as a bean reference.

Comment: Doesn't work for me (spring mvc 3.1) - maybe there is something more that needs to be done? Going with Samit's solution.

Comment: The problem is that when you test validators using MockMvc and this kind of injection you'll have problems. May be the other solution will be preferred in this case

Comment: It is possible to autowire HttpServletRequest also into non request-scoped beans, because for HttpServletRequest Spring will generate a proxy HttpServletRequest which is aware how to get the actual instance of request. So it is safe to autowire request even if your controller is singleton scoped.

Comment: **Warning for Spring <=3.1 users** the autowiring will not work running tests.

Comment: `Field request in xx.xx.xx.beans.i18n required a bean of type 'javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest' that could not be found`

Comment: Note that this works in other (non-request-scoped) beans as well, but for wider-scoped beans, it's best to inject `ObjectFactory<HttpServletRequest>` and get the current request from that where needed.

Answer (score 165):

Spring exposes the current `HttpServletRequest` object (as well as the current `HttpSession` object) through a *wrapper* object of type `ServletRequestAttributes`. This wrapper object is bound to ThreadLocal and is obtained by calling the `static` method `RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()`.

`ServletRequestAttributes` provides the method `getRequest()` to get the current request, `getSession()` to get the current session and other methods to get the attributes stored in both the scopes. The following code, though a bit ugly, should get you the current request object anywhere in the application:

```
HttpServletRequest curRequest = 
((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes())
.getRequest();
```

Note that the `RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()` method returns an interface and needs to be typecasted to `ServletRequestAttributes` that implements the interface.

---

**Spring Javadoc:** [RequestContextHolder](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestContextHolder.html) | [ServletRequestAttributes](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/ServletRequestAttributes.html)

Comment: Injection is good resolution, but I have found problems with MockMvc testing Spring validators which inject HttpServletRequest. So if you want both mock tests and production code running properly this should be the choice.

Comment: @Neyko Why is it? for mock test(Unit test?), you can inject mock HttpServletRequest or whatever you want.. isn't it? Or you can use MockHttpServletRequest I guess?

Comment: Is it safe to be used in a singleton-scoped service instance?

Answer (score 8):

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48574780/autowired-httpservletrequest-vs-passing-as-parameter-best-practice) you can also inject the `HttpServletRequest` as a method param, e.g.:

```
public MyResponseObject myApiMethod(HttpServletRequest request, ...) {
    ...
}
```