# I've injected HttpServletRequest into a bean. How do I unit test it?

Tags: spring, junit

I have a bean in which [I've injected an `HttpServletRequest` using the `@Autowired` annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320674/spring-how-do-i-inject-an-httpservletrequest-into-a-request-scoped-bean/3324233#3324233).

This injection works correctly when the application context is a web application Context. That's not the case for application contexts for JUnit tests with Spring.

How can I test this bean ? Maybe I can mock an http request, but then how to inject this mock in the bean ?

This is on Spring 3.0 and Junit 4.4

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Create a bean of type `MockHttpServletRequest` and add it to your test context. This should then be autowired into your target bean.

Comment: Thanks, but how to "add it to your test context"? [Here](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?69604-Adding-beans-to-application-context) guys haven't found a solution.