# Spring web service - How do i extract the request?

Tags: java, spring, servlets, mime

I have a web service that is processed on the Spring end as follows:

```
    @POST
    @Path("/processRequest")
    @Consumes("multipart/mixed")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public String processRequest(@Context ServletContext servletContext, MultipartInput input) {

        return addAccout(servletContext, input);
    }
```

The request will come in as a multipart/mixed request and will look something like this:

```
--productBoundary
Content-Type: text/xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<product>
     <name>ProductA</name>
</product>

--productBoundary
Content-Type: text/xml

ZGF0YRBAAABn5///////////////5///Z+fn///n////////5////////2f//2f//+f//+f////n/
///////52f//////2f//////2f/////5////////+f/////Z+f///////////////9n//9nZ/9n////5+f///9
<snip>
//+f//////2f/////////5//n//////////9n

--productBoundary--
```

The request will come in as a mutipart/mixed. I can use Resteasy's object shown in the processRequest's method parameters to extract each part of the multipart/mixed message. What i would like to do though is to get the message as it is unmodified with its headers and everything else. Is this possible?

I need to be able to store the request exactly as it came in. Using the MultipartInput structure means i have modified the request. Is there anyway i can get the request as it came in (with all its headers) without modifying it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Docs here:](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-3.1.html#d0e1654)

3.1.18 @RequestPart Annotation On Controller Method Arguments

This new annotation provides access to the content of a "multipart/form-data" request part. See Section 16.10.5, “Handling a file upload request from programmatic clients” and Section 16.10, “Spring's multipart (file upload) support”.

Comment: Thanks - @RequestPart still splits the request. I am interested in the request as a whole so that i can store it - Exactly as it came in with the headers(i.e. boundary, content-type etc)

Comment: This question sums it up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320674/spring-how-do-i-inject-an-httpservletrequest-into-a-request-scoped-bean
A way to get the HttpServletRequest, which allows you to get the raw headers.