# Spring mvc request scope context across threads

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-mvc, requestcontext

In a spring MVC web application, I wanna store user information at the request scope, in the **filer** or **interceptor** I will build the user information and store it and use it later within this request.I know in spring I can create **request scope spring beans**, but these beans can only be accessed within the request thread(maybe the child thread).However I will access the user information in the thread pool.So the build in request scope spring bean may not suitable for me. Any tip for store information share among threads within the request scope？

Comment: Check this out, see if it helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320674/spring-how-do-i-inject-an-httpservletrequest-into-a-request-scoped-bean  You can `@Autowire` the request into your beans.

Comment: @bipotato911 are you trying to build login or user authentication ? for that you should be using spring security. And if you want to share some data across multiple requests for a particular user you can use session.

Comment: @gajendrakumar  actually I want to share data within one request but among threads.When user make a request I will collect the user info and the app info, then in the following business logic I will use the information in the thread pool task