# Spring Data Rest - How to receive Headers in @RepositoryEventHandler

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I'm using the latest Spring Data Rest and I'm handling the event "**before create**". The requirement I have is to capture also the HTTP Headers submitted to the **POST** endpoint for the model "**Client**". However, the interface for the **RepositoryEventHandler** does not expose that.

```
@Component
@RepositoryEventHandler
public class ClientEventHandler {

  @Autowired
  private ClientService clientService;

  @HandleBeforeCreate
  public void handleClientSave(Client client) {
    ...
    ...
  }
}
```

How can we handle events and capture the HTTP Headers? I'd like to have access to the parameter like Spring MVC that uses the **@RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers**.

Comment: I haven't tested but can you `@Autowired` the `HttpServletRequest ` directly like   `@Autowired
 private HttpServletRequest request;` then use `request.getHeader("user-agent")` .Can you pls check example here https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-http-request-header-in-java/

Comment: HttpServletRequest is not a Spring managed bean so cannot be autowired.

Comment: Without a custom controller one idea would be a Servlet filter that binds the required values to the current Thread using a ThreadLocal and makes them available via a static call. See for example http://veerasundar.com/blog/2010/11/java-thread-local-how-to-use-and-code-sample/ or http://blog.smartbear.com/programming/how-and-when-to-use-javas-threadlocal-object/

Comment: @AlanHay yes the request can be autowired.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply autowire the request to a field of your EventHandler

```
@Component
@RepositoryEventHandler
public class ClientEventHandler {
    private  HttpServletRequest request;

    public ClientEventHandler(HttpServletRequest request) {
        this.request = request;
    }

    @HandleBeforeCreate
    public void handleClientSave(Client client) {
        System.out.println("handling events like a pro");
        Enumeration<String> names = request.getHeaderNames();
        while (names.hasMoreElements())
            System.out.println(names.nextElement());
    }
}
```

In the code given I used Constructor Injection, which I think is the cleanest, but Field or Setter injection should work just as well.

I actually found the solution on stackoverflow: [Spring: how do I inject an HttpServletRequest into a request-scoped bean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320674/spring-how-do-i-inject-an-httpservletrequest-into-a-request-scoped-bean)

Oh, and I just noticed @Marc proposed this in thecomments ... but I actually tried it :)

Comment: You forgot to add `@Autowired`

Comment: It's not necessary if there is a single constructor

Comment: One may ask himself (I did) how it is possible that the injected `HttpServletRequest` actually references the current request although the `ClientEventHandler` class is a `@Component` (and thus a singleton). Well, when a scoped bean (e.g. request-scoped like `HttpServletRequest`) is injected into a bean of a longer-lived scope (like `@Component`) then in fact an AOP proxy is injected in place of the bean. The proxy then dispatches calls to the actual bean instance in the current scope.

Comment: [Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-other-injection)